# Textmate : how to complete word use ESC in multi tabs?

Tags: autocomplete, textmate

When I use VIM and I have 3 tabs, I use the keystrike `<C-P>` and it will complete a word in 3 tabs. When I use Textmate and I have 3 tabs, I use the keystrike `ESC` abd it will complete a word only in the current tab.

How could I complete a word in all tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. TextMate only uses the current file for completion.

Stick with Vim.